# Using sar command in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, sar

I'm developing a small utility in Java, that monitors a remote Linux machine's cpu. I'm using using `sar` command to monitor it. The problem is, when i write `sar 1 1` it takes some time to get cpu usage. I tried `sar 0` but it's showing same cpu values instead of online cpu usage. What can i do to take cpu usage instantly?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be:

```
top
```

or

```
top | grep <App_name>
```

or

```
 ps -p <app_pid> -o %cpu
```

**Edit**

To obtain only the number of % use of cpu of a certain pid:

```
ps -p PID -o %cpu | sed 's/[^0-9]//g' | tr -d '\n'
```

or

```
ps -p PID -o %cpu | sed -n 2p | sed 's/ //'
```

Comment: you need of the number without '%'? take a look at edit

Comment: +1 for your efforts.what if i want total cpu usage? not by pid?